# C# Limiting setter value

Tags: c#, math, properties, setter, limiting

I'm currently trying to implement properties and in particular limiting my setter. For example, i have a 'Money' float field that i'd like it so you can add/subtract values to it but when it's at 0 make it so that it can no longer be subtracted but it can however still be added to.

I see that in the code below that once 'Money' reaches 0 it'll be always stuck at 0. Is there some way to check whether the setter is being added to? I understand that you can check it in the AddMoney or SubtractMoney methods but was more curious if it's possible to do so in the setter.

```
public float Money {
    get {
        return this._money;
    }

    set {

        if (_money <= 0){
            _money = 0;
        } else {
            _money = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
void AddMoney(float addAmount){
    Money += addAmount;
}

void SubtractMoney(float subtractAmount){
    Money -= subtractAmount;
}
```

Comment: You can check if the `value` is negative...

Comment: Side note: I strongly suspect your assignment expects you to put validation to some other place rather than setter...

Comment: never never never never never ever store money in floats.  use decimal

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh is it bad practice to put it in the setter?

Comment: No, range checking is reasonable in setter... It lead to strange and non-intuitive behavior for number-like values (like `v = v - 5 + 3` is generally expected to be equivalent to `v = v -5; v = v + 3;` but it is not the case for such properties). But again if this is some sort of homework the assignment is likely calls for something different as `Susbstract(decimal amount)` should usually check values by itself to guarantee expected logic and throw reasonable errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test if the value is negative don't change the `Money` value :

```
        set {

                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    _money = value;
                }
                else
                {
                //You may throw exception, or log a warning   
                }
            }
```